# Oracle merge and third party tables

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I work with merge operation like in this example:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9016.htm

How I can make insert into third party table inside "when matched" and "when not matched" clauses?

UPDATE: May be possible set some flags inside this clauses? For using it at next procedure steps - for execute insert ...

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to do. Do mean just a table in a different schema, which you can specify in the `into` clause? Or that you want to insert into a table that is different from the `into` target? Which wouldn't really make sense, and would suggest you're using the wrong kind of statement...

Comment: i want execute merge and parallel insert data into another table with merged/inserted record identifier

Comment: That isn't much clearer... you want to `merge into table_a ...` but insert into a *different* table? Then that isn't a merge.

Comment: This is a merge at table_a and parallel operation with table_z with   result identifier from merge

Answer (score 0):

Considering you want to benefit from the `MERGE` clause to actually `UPDATE` a table, your suggestion about flags is a pretty good idea IMO. Suppose you want to merge `TAB_A` and `TAB_B` into `TAB_C`, you would 1st need to `ALTER TABLE TAB_A ADD (FLAG VARCHAR2(1));`.

Then the `MERGE` would consists in setting up the flags:

```
MERGE INTO tab_a a
USING (tab_b) b
ON (...)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET a.flag = 'U'
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (..., FLAG) VALUES (..., 'I')
;
```

You can then update `TAB_C` like:

```
INSERT INTO tab_c
SELECT ...
FROM tab_a a
WHERE a.flag = 'I';
```

and the same kind of `UPDATE` for lines with 'U' flag. Don't forget to reset the flag in `TAB_A` when you're finished !